# Creating a Slide-able divs overflow wheel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

How can i turn a group of links overflowed like this
[image]

to become a Slide-able by mouse or touch wheel showing all links by sliding like this
[image]

The red arrows is for people who would like to click but still can be pulled by mouse or touch, I can't find any example about how to make this at all using the jquery ui or even ready script, Can someone please explain to me how to make this? using only `CSS` and `JavaScript` if possible, Or `jQuery` if it is faster.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/onejdc/swQ7J/4/ might help you

Comment: @shivamGupta Yes, that exactly what i'm looking for, But how can i make it Draggable?

Comment: you mean draggable or scrollable. If draggable, can you explain what behaviour you are expecting. Draggable would be dragging item from one position to another.

Comment: @shivamGupta I think draggable would be a wrong usage if what i mean, I guess it is sliding? Like clicking and pulling the mouse left or right to scroll, instead of clicking on the right\left div

Comment: Source  : http://darsa.in/sly/  Demo :    http://codepen.io/ritz078/pen/bEYOov   Other than this if you wish to write custom component with such behaviour you might need to target scroll events and call same functions as left click and right click are called.

Comment: @shivamGupta well, that solves it all